Crystal Report Export data only issue
I create a crystalreport on aspx using c# and it work correctly on export as a pdf,xlsx,xls,csv,rpt but in data only (xlsx) some column is missing and order switching. I use crystalreportViewer13.
export as a dataonly(xlsx)
